# Why has my rep not increased?

Tags: support, reputation

I have 7 and 19 votes from ["Man" is to "womanizer" as "woman" is to what?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69129/man-is-to-womanizer-as-woman-is-to-what/) and [Polite alternatives to "as soon as possible"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69101/polite-alternatives-to-as-soon-as-possible/) respectively, but my points have hardly increased since yesterday.

I checked out [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/17795/shyam?tab=reputation), but again there seems to be some issue with the count and tally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations! You've reached the 200 rep/day cap, which applies to reputation from upvotes, downvotes, and suggested edits. (N.B. Stack Exchange uses UTC time, so 1 day is from midnight UTC of one day to midnight UTC of the next.)

Past the rep cap, you can't earn any more reputation until the next day; however, I'm happy to let you know it's already the next day (technically, you reached the rep cap yesterday SE-time), so you can still earn rep right now.

There's a twofold reason there's a cap in place: 1) we don't want people to burn out too quickly, so we encourage you not to spend too much time here :), and 2) we don't want someone to gain a lot of privileges that they might unknowingly abuse for one post that's really, really popular because it's been linked that day on Reddit (it's better if the votes are spread out over time, as that's usually more indicative of good quality that keeps getting upvoted instead of linkspammed on some site).

Comment: But I have earned >200 on three days - is that the max before cap is introduced?

Comment: Also, my 2 cents: this rule makes little sense to me. The effort I put in is not always correlated to the upvotes I get. For single word answers, I could earn 20 upvotes, for well-researched long answers, I could earn just 2. Points and the time I spend here are also not related; in a democratic system this cap deprives me of what I really deserve :|

Comment: @Shyam It's possible to earn more than 200 rep in a UTC day, as the cap only applies to upvotes, downvotes, and suggested edits. For example, each accepted answer earns you +15 rep that does not count into the rep cap.

Comment: @Shyam: Yes, the system is imperfect. Sometimes we get a lot of votes for the first thing that pops into our heads, other times we do hours worth of research and only get two or three (maybe because the question is too old for the answer to get noticed by then). In the long run, though, it probably all evens out, so, as the saying goes, "[Turn that frown upside-down](http://cdn.buzznet.com/assets/users16/xsecretxpoetx/default/turn-frown-upside-down--large-msg-122369153235.jpg)!" (or, in this case, turn that _vertical bar_ into a _close-paren_.)

Comment: @J.R. With all due respect, I don't think anything ever just evens out. #2 does seem like a critically and sensibly purposed reason, though.